Root of an irreducible polynomial $g(x)$ over a finite field K = \frac{$\mathbb{F}$_p}{f(x)}
Question: Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ of degree n are irreducible polynomials over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where p a prime. Show that $g(x)$ has a root in $K = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$.
How I approached We know that there exists an isomorphism between K and the field $L = \mathbb{F}_{p}{[x]}/(g(x))$, and for the isomorphism to be well-defined, the roots have to, the root of $f(x)$ has to go to the root of $g(x)$. But how can I show that there exists a root of $g(x)$ in $K$?
Any hints would be appreciated!

I guess you probably need $f,g$ to have the same degree?

But that demonstrates that there exists an isomormphism between $K$ and $L$, because of the homomorphism $\phi$ that sends $g(x)$ from $\mathbb{F}_p$ to $K$ using the first isomorphism theorem. But I don't understand how I could deduce that there exists a root of $g(x)$ in K. Or is it because it is in the kernel of $\phi$?

Is there any way to find it explicitly?

How did you get $K \cong L$

They have the same number of elements, because the polynomials $f$ and $g$ have same degree.

I am sorry, I forgot to write deg(f)=deg(g)=n. I edited it now.

Hint: $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x$ and any root of $f$ or $g$ should satisfy $x^{p^n}-x = 0$.

Do you mean $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$? That is, a quotient ring of a polynomial ring, which is a field if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible.

There is no need for a root of $f(x)$ to go to a root of $g(x)$. Surely a root of $f(x)$ should go to a root of $f(x)$! But there is no explicit formula for one. An existence result based on the hint from RHspqr.

Okay, I understand. And Yes, I meant $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$

Since $\mathbb{F}_{p} / (f) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p} / (g)$ and $g(x)$ has a root $\overline{x}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p} / (g)$, $g(x)$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_{p} / (f(x))$.
